# php foreach JavaScript validator

Tags: javascript, php

```
<? foreach($words as $word): ?>
    <li>
        <form id="" method="post" action="">
            <span id="first">
                <?php print $check = $word['Word']['id'] ?>
            </span>
            <span>EN:</span>
            <input type="text" name="second" id="second" />
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Check" onclick="validate()" />
        </form>
        <script>
            function validate() {
                var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
                var first = <? php echo $check ?> ;
                if (second == first) {
                    alert('Ok!');
                } else {
                    alert(first);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </li>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Problem with a variable 'first', always equal last id into table and never equal variable 'second'. When I try alert(first); always last id.

Answer (score 0):

There will be `first` as many times the loop runs. And every time the loop runs the value of `first` will be overwritten by the next loop. So it is always be the last value in `first`.

Use some data attribute and use jquery -

```
<input type="text" name="second" class="second" data-check="<?php echo $check ?>"/>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Check" class="validate_button"/>
```

And with jquery -

```
$('.validate_button').on('click', function() {
    var second = $(this).siblings('.second').val();
    var first = $(this).siblings('.second').data('check');
    if (second == first){
         alert('Ok!');
    } else {
         alert(first);
    }
    // Or return something
});
```

Comment: var second must be input string and equal this in var first